# Trying to show only 4 results in each <ul> element

Tags: php, css

I have one div class="pdfs" where I want to show some links that will open pdfs.

Inside this div I have two divs, because I want to have one block of pdfs at left and other block at right, like this:

[image]

And now Im getting pdfs from database, and it is working fine.

But I just want to show a maximum of 4 pdfs in my `<div class="pdfs1">`, and If there are more then 4 pdfs I want to show them inside my `<div class="pdfs2">`, to get this links at right, like I have in my image.

For example, if I have 5 pdfs in database, I want to show 4 in my `<div class="pdfs1">` and one in mine `<div class="pdfs2">`.

Im trying with if condition but it its not working, can you give a little help?

```
$readPdfs =  $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM pdfs");
$readPdfs->execute();

echo '<div  class="pdfs">';
    echo '<h3>Pdfs to see:</h3>';
    echo '<ul class="pdfs1">';
        while ($readPdfsResult = $readPdfs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
         $folder  = 'pdfs/';
         echo '<li> <a  href="'.$folder.'/'.$readPdfsResult['pdf'].'">'.$readPdfsResult['pdf'].'</a></li>';
        }
    echo '</ul>';

    echo '<ul class="pdfs2">';
         //but here I want to show only if there are more than 4 pdfs
         echo '<li> <a  href="'.$folder.'/'.$readPdfsResult['pdf'].'">'.$readPdfsResult['pdf'].'</a></li>';
    echo '</ul>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
```

Comment: This question has nothing to do with databases, but the whole way you're doing this is wrong. You should rarely be echoing HTML code, and you should certainly not loop on a fetch directly in the view...

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But I never said this question was about database. I just talk about database to explain problem in the best way that I thought. And why it is wrong? sorry if it looks like a noob question, but I always do like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep track of the number of rows seen so far, and end each `UL` when 4 have been shown:

```
$folder  = 'pdfs/';
$rows = 0;

echo '<ul class="pdfs1">';
while (($rows < 4) && ($readPdfsResult = $readPdfs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)))
{
  $fn = htmlspecialchars($readPdfsResult['pdf']);
  echo "<li> <a href='$folder/$fn'>$fn</a></li>";
  ++$rows;
}
echo '</ul>';

$rows = 0;

echo '<ul class="pdfs2">';
while (($rows < 4) && ($readPdfsResult = $readPdfs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)))
{
  $fn = htmlspecialchars($readPdfsResult['pdf']);
  echo "<li> <a href='$folder/$fn'>$fn</a></li>";
  ++$rows;
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Im here trying to do what you said, it looks like a good solution! But it isnt working. If I do exactly like you said, I think this enter in a infinite loop, because the website dont works, when I click in some link nothing works. So I change your second while for while(($rows > 4) &&.... and like this the website back to normal, but I Have 5 pdfs and Im getting just 4 in my first <ul> like I had before your solution!

Comment: Forget what I said before, I was putting a ++$rows more than necessary. Thank you very much, you really help me! Im still a beginner and I was here whole day trying to find a solution! Thanks!